# Hiding tab characters in Vim

Tags: vim, go

I've just begun learning Go, and upon running `go fmt`, I am finding tab `^I` characters appear in my code:

```
package main
import "fmt"

func main() {
  ^Ifmt.Println("Hello world!")
}
```

Is there a way I can configure Vim to not display these characters, while still preserving the tabs in the file itself?

Comment: Check `:verbose set list?` to check whether `list` option is set, and where. `:help list`, `:help listchars`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following Amadan's suggestion, I edited the file that `:verbose set list?` returned, which for me is `~/.vim/init/options.vim`. Removing `set list` solved the problem for me

Comment: Why did you put that there if you don't know what it does and don't want its effect?

Comment: I'm using a custom Vim config that came on my machine

Answer (score 0):

Just remove this line in your configuration file:
`:set listchars=tab:\(whatever chracter)\`

`set list` may be useful later for character editing. I wouldn't recommend just deleting it without knowing what you are doing.